# Unable to install windows error 0x80070057

Tags: windows, boot, partitioning

I have an HP envy 15 which earlier had Windows 8.1 installed (and now absolutely nothing).

Microsoft is giving a free upgrade to Windows 10.

I tried to clean install windows 10 on my laptop, to totally clean my hard disk I made a bootable drive, and booted with it to install Windows

I clicked custom install and after that I pressed <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to open a command shell and I ran the following commands

```
diskpart
select disk 0
clean
```

After this it encountered an error and showed that it was unable to format the drive.

I rebooted again with a bootable USB, but I found that my whole hard disk was formatted (it showed unallocated space 900gb without any partition)

I made a new partition of about 100gb and tried to install windows in it
 but when I formatted it an error was showed up that windows cannot format the partition:

> error code 0x80070057

Can anyone help me to solve this?

(I was able to install Ubuntu in my laptop but I deleted it because I found it useless for me)

Comment: Take a look at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2476568: This error occurs because the partition that is reserved for system is damaged (Error 0x80070057 when you format a hard disk drive)

Comment: Already Tried that 

Comment: Use Dban boot disk to wipe the drive. then do a clean install and do not use the diskpart commands, just select the unallocated partition and hit enter to continue installing W10, the W10 installer will automatically format the drive with 2 partitions, one for winre and one for the OS.  http://www.dban.org/

Comment: Dban only needs to run for 15 minutes, no need to overwrite the entire drive.

Answer (score -1):

First of all using diskpart to wipe your harddisk clean wasn't a good idea. It destroys any boot and recovery partitions which would be useful in case of problems like this. Not to mention you need to install Windows 10 via Media Creation Tool to benefit from free upgrade (not clean install). You need to downgrade to Windows 8.1 (no need to worry about activation as it should read your key from UEFI) then use Media Creation Tool to upgrade to Windows 10. You can download Windows 8.1 directly from [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows8). Also please refer to [Microsoft FAQ](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/faq) page for other questions you might have about this process.

Comment: I know that was a bit too baad idea,(i lost my recovery drive) but i am having iso for windows 8, 8.1, 10 and all of them failed

Comment: Is there any way to completely reset my harddrive to the factory settings

Comment: You can (and probably should) use GParted to clean your harddisk then you can make a clean install of 8.1 Gparted tutorial : http://gparted.org/display-doc.php%3Fname%3Dhelp-manual

Comment: You basically already did, now you need a clean install.  You don't have to do anything special from command line when you are trying to install/upgrade just delete and create a new partition at the first screenshot in the article duDE posted.  Are you sure they are full install ISO's or upgrade?

Comment: i remember diskpart having issues while working with gpt drives (that or i'm being too hard on it :) ) that's why i recommended gparted.

Comment: another down-vote another invisible explanation. carry on.

Comment: I used gparted which was quite user friendly as well as dban which took more than 12hrs         Final result-- Windows is still having that error

Comment: Now i have sent the laptop to hp, lets see what they will do. I will post answer if hp gets what wrong with my laptop